# How to remove index.php and default store code from url in magento?

Tags: magento-1, url

I want to remove default store code and index.php from my url.

I have installed one module for remove default store code form url but after remove store core from url my site can not open without index.php.

If I allow default store code in url than I can remove index.php and site working fine.

so can anyone help to remove both("index.php" and "store code") from magento URL.

Thanks
Dhvanit

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the index.php in the frontend URLs performing the following steps in Magento's admin section:

In **System -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engines Optimizations**, select **YES**.

Edit the `/installdir/.htaccess` and uncomment the line:

```
RewriteBase /magento/
```

In my case the subdirectory Magento is in is called `magento`, so change it to your subdirectory path if it is different.

[For hide store url see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25743822/magento-how-to-hide-the-default-store-view-code-from-the-url)